# Difference between Server Generated HTML and JavaScript enable application

Tags: javascript, html, database

What is the Difference between Server Genertated HTML and Javascirpt enabled web application. I have a confusion In javascirpt enable web applications we have a data in JSON and and we use javascrips Ajax , Angularjs to perform different operations and What is the server generated html. Is it in wordpress where the whole html page is loaded from the serverside Database?

Answer (score 0):

**WordPress** is based on php 
**PHP** generate html for serve the client, take the information from the database, this is server generated html

 **Javascript** is a client script so html is generated from client